# Can we only get the web page header information and not the body? (Mechanize)

Tags: python, mechanize, screen-scraping

What if I only need to download the page if it has not changed since the last download?
What is the best way? can I get the size of the page first, then compare the decide if it has changed, if so, I ask for download else skip?

I plan to use (python) mechanize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the request should be a  [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html), not a GET:

> **9.4 HEAD**
>
> The HEAD method is identical to GET
> except that the server MUST NOT return
> a message-body in the response. The
> metainformation contained in the HTTP
> headers in response to a HEAD request
> SHOULD be identical to the information
> sent in response to a GET request.
> This method can be used for obtaining
> metainformation about the entity
> implied by the request without
> transferring the entity-body itself.
> This method is often used for testing
> hypertext links for validity,
> accessibility, and recent
> modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be
> cacheable in the sense that the
> information contained in the response
> MAY be used to update a previously
> cached entity from that resource. If
> the new field values indicate that the
> cached entity differs from the current
> entity (as would be indicated by a
> change in Content-Length, Content-MD5,
> ETag or Last-Modified), then the cache
> MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

See here [How can I perform a HEAD request with the mechanize library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137580/how-can-i-perform-a-head-request-with-the-mechanize-library)?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can get more information in python mechanize by setting like this

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_debug_http(True)
br.set_debug_redirects(True)
... Your code here ...
```

by doing this, you can get valuable header information of the page